# Asynchronous cURL Request

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous

Can anyone help me to make this function work asynchronous?

```
function connect($url, $para)
{
    if (empty($para)) {
        return false;
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($para));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: -1 for lack of any research

Comment: I did my research but i've failed to make it work. That request is looped until response will be correct. I don't know anything about curl so i was hoping someone can help me.

Comment: I don't see how this was too obvious? How would you know that you want to do a "fresh connect" to make it asynchronous if you are not familiar with the framework?

Answer (score 0):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);`

Should do the trick

Comment: I've tried it before posting question. Here is whole script: [link](http://pastebin.com/sV8xAhp3)